# CollectionView Cells not loading in View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to load in some data in a feed based off of a user's data through Firebase, however, it isn't working. My application is currently organized so that the user enters on CustomTabBarController and is verified for login and that a profile has been created, retrieving it if needed. Then, I send the user to the feed by:

```
// Go to home feed
        let navController = self.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController
        let feedVC = navController?.topViewController as? FeedViewController
        if feedVC != nil {
            feedVC!.getProfilePhotos()
        }
```

My first question - is this the correct way to load in the FeedViewController on a CustomTabBarController? I also make a call to get the profile data ahead of time.

The getProfilePhotos is a set of delegate and protocols, and returns the following way (I have verified that it correctly retrieves photoURLs). The debugger then thinks that there are no more methods to fire after this.

```
func feedProfilePhotosRetrieved(photoURLs: [String]) {

    // Set photos array and reload the tableview
    self.photoURLs = photoURLs
    cardCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is my FeedViewController class, it's properties and viewDidLoad()/viewDidAppear()

```
var feedModel = FeedViewModel()
var associates = UserProfile.shared().associates
var photoURLs = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var cardCollectionView: UICollectionView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    associates = UserProfile.shared().associates
    feedModel.delegate = self
    cardCollectionView.delegate = self
    cardCollectionView.dataSource = self
    cardCollectionView.register(CardCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "sectionCell")
    cardCollectionView.reloadData()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getProfilePhotos()
}
```

This is where I create the cells in the collection view. I put a breakpoint at the declaration of "cell", but it isn't firing.

```
extension FeedViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return associates.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "sectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell
    let card = UserProfile.shared().associates[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = card.name
    cell.poscomp.text = card.title + ", " + card.company

    // Photo that we're trying to display
    let p = photoURLs[indexPath.row]

    // Display photo
    cell.downloadPhoto(p)
    cell.layer.transform = animateCell(cellFrame: cell.frame)
    return cell
} }
```

Are there any blatantly visible errors that I'm missing? Do I have to call the above function when reloadingData() as well? Thanks for your help and let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method numberOfItemsInSection should return `photoURLs.count`.

```
extension FeedViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photoURLs.count
}
```